# can someone help me understand what is happening in this code?

Tags: javascript

Im struggling to understand what this calculation is `return base * power(base, exponent - 1);` in the following code. Does base get multiplied with the `power` function that has the base inside it again?

```
var power = function(base,exponent){
      if(exponent === 0){
          return 1;
      } else {
          return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
      }
};

power(2,2);
```

Does this mean that `return base = 2*(2,2-1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does base get multiplied with the power function that has the base inside it again?

Yes, absolutely, and that's how this recursive implementation actually works.

If you expand `power(10, 4)` for example you get:

```
power(10, 4)
= 10 * power(10, 3)
= 10 * 10 * power(10, 2)
= 10 * 10 * 10 * power(10, 1)
= 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * power(10, 0)
= 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 1
```

It should hopefully be clear from this expansion exactly *why* this is a valid (albeit slow) way to calculate exponents.

Comment: This is a complete answer. But just FYI, this is much more than slow, function calls are really expensive, when you need performance. And beside that this only works for positive integers as exponent.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2 raised to the 0 power or 2<sup>0</sup> which is always 1.

It's a recursive method to calculate the exponents. Although [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) works better.

So if the exponent is zero the recursion ends `if (exponent === 0) return 1`. If the exponent is not zero. Then the method calls itself decrementing the exponent variable.

The magic happens `return base * power(base, exponent - 1);` once the method `return 1;` the values are pulled off the stack and multiplied by each other.

This is not the best way to do this.

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry im just trying to understand what value actually gets returned here when that calculation is made?

Answer (score 1):

It is ***custom*** implementation of built-in method [`Math.pow`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp). So these statements output same result:

```
console.log(power(2,8)); // 256
console.log(Math.pow(2, 8)); // 256
```

In case you need that, use `Math.pow` instead.